# how to when submit, and then use the status code to output warning in ui? angular 2 and above

Tags: angular, angular2-template, angular2-forms, angular2-services, http-status-codes

Requirements:

1. enter choice, press submit.

myapi = api;

```
submit(){
    this.getDa.postDa(myapi,this.defaultForm)
    .subscribe(
    (response)=>{
        console.log("response: "+response);
    },
    error=>{
        console.log("ERROR, CANNOT SUBMIT");
    }
}
```

So what i need to do is to change the submit method into something that can get the status code so that i can change it into number or string or whatever to be use with this

form.html

```
<button type="submit" (click)="submit()" class="btn btn-block btn-primary">
    Submit
</button>
<ng-template [ngIf]="statusCode == 301">
    <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
    <strong>Warning!</strong> ERROR 301. Please try again.
           </div>  
</ng-template>
```

2. This is where i have problem. It is not working. any suggestions to make mine more usable? both the service and the component.ts?

UPDATED CODE
    export class GetService {

```
constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

getData(url):Observable<any>{
  return this.http.get(url)
}
```

this is how I did the submit to call the method in service.ts, but it is not working.
in form.ts

```
submit(){
        this.getservice.getData(myapi)
        .map((res:Response) =>{
            if (res) {
                if (res.status===200) {
                    this.statusCode = res.status;
                    return this.extractData(res);
                }
                else if (res.status>200||res.status==500){
                    this.statusCode = res.status;
                    return this.extractData(res);
                }
            }
        }).catch((error:any)=>{
            if (error.status>500){
                return Observable.throw(new Error(error.status));
            }
        })
    }
```

I've changed the coding and it is a bit clearer to me now. thank you for those who already help me ! but i still cannot make it work. to extract the data and use it in html. is the problem lies in my service.ts or in form.ts? or is it in form.html? can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

```
submit(){
    this.getService.getStatus(this.defaultForm)(
      (res) => { 
           this.statusCode=res.status,
      (err) => { this.statusCode=err.status) }
    )
}
```

but, IMPORTANT!, try use httpClient, not the "old" http

Comment: Sorry but i still have error with my service.ts.  return this.http.post(myapi, '/items', { item: item }. "Argument of type {item:any} is not assignable to parameter of type 'RequestOptionArgs'. Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'item' does not exist in type 'RequestOptionsArgs'."  What does that mean?

Comment: the arguments are http.post(URL,BODY), that is, write  http.post(myapi+'/items',{item:item})